# Enable SSO (Single Sign ON) on AirWatch

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, airwatch

I'm investigating to develop iOS App on AirWatch.
I set up as the following (Reference : /AirWatch/HelpSystem/en/Content/Core_Guides/MAM/T/SSO_Configure.htm) on AirWatch Console for enable SSO.

1. Navigate to Groups & Settings > All Settings > Apps > Settings and Policies > Security Policies.
2. Set Single Sign On to Enabled to give end-users access to all AirWatch applications and to maintain a persistent login.

However, SSO is not enabled on distributed iOS Apps...
Please suggest, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To enable SSO in your iOS app, AirWatch recommands integrating AirWatch SDK into your app. Then, configure a SDK profil with Integrated Authentication configured.

Basic documentation can be found the AirWatch developpers website: [AirWatch Single Sign-On](http://developer.air-watch.com/single-sign-on/)